# Nuxt2 redirect with router base

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app that uses `router: { base: “/admin” }`. On `/` I have deployed another Nuxt app.
In the admin app I have a link that links to a route in the main app (`/login`) but for some reason I am always redirected to `/admin/login`.

Any idea how can I handle the router redirects manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the scope of the second Nuxt app, you will of course be redirected to the given path prefixed with `admin` (because the 2nd Nuxt app doesn't know anything about the rest), this is not a bug.

Not sure why you do have 2 differents apps but if you want to force a navigation to the 1st Nuxt app, you could use `window.location.href` or an `a` HTML tag, rather than using a `nuxt-link`.

That way, you will be going to the other location, nuking your SPA (but you're leaving it for another one anyway) and getting on the other one properly.

You will not be able to transition from an SPA to another SPA without an actual page navigation anyway.

Comment: Already using `<a/>` tag.

Comment: @Sartre should be working well so.

Comment: You are right but I am redirecting from a middleware as well, and unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: @Sartre please share some of your code here.